# Reliable sources on house prices in the UK/London

Tags: first-time-home-buyer, online-data-source, london

I would like to understand whether the prices of homes/flats in some London boroughs (say Haringey or Islington) are going up or down in the last few months/years, and by how much. Even better, if possible I want to analyse smaller areas of London, for example catchment areas of some schools (0.5 km in radius). How would I approach such a problem apart from tracking myself the prices of sold houses for the next 2 years?

The reason I am asking the question is that so far I am getting quite contradictory information about flat prices in London from various sources (FT, BBC, Rightmove, so on).  I can't even figure out whether they go up or down, and I would like to avoid buying a flat now if it was going up for the last year or so and there are some indications that prices started to slide down.

Comment: This might be on-topic if you remove the statement specifically asking for a tool/website.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica Thank you for the suggestion for improvement of the question. I tried my best to explain it better and removed the request for tool/website

Comment: Assuming you had *every piece of data in the universe*, "if it is exactly the local maximum" how would you know that?

Comment: @Fattie, thanks for the comment. The word "exactly" was put there just for a dramatic effect (because it's bad for me, since I want to buy a house). I'll removed it a slightly rephrased the last sentence. What I am looking for is exactly a lot of data

Comment: just FYI over in the US there's a site "zillow.com".  very simply, go to any location, any street, and it just, literally, shows you every single sale price that has ever happened on every property (recently, in the past, whatever).  I guess that's what U need in the UK ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't help feeling (based on this and your previous questions on similar topics) that you are going about things the wrong way.

There is a website that provides individual sold house price data: https://nethouseprices.com/ which lets you search down to the "first half of postcode" level, but how can you tell from that whether "house prices are going up or down"? You can't, because if you see that property A sold for £X and property B sold for £X+Y, you don't know whether property B is equivalent to property A or not - larger property, better condition, better amenities, or even just the owners had a better estate agent who was able to negotiate a better price.

The reason you read conflicting information is because there are different kinds of analysis you can do on the raw data - is the mean house price rising/falling? or the median? or the maximum price paid in the area? or the mean / medium / maximum amount above original asking price? or the spot price of some kind of house that the analyst has decided is a "typical house" in this area? These signals could be going in different directions and different analysts will decide that different ones are more important (or more likely to generate a news headline that will get clicks / views).

So let us say you want to do your own analysis and so you devote your life for a year or two to collecting data and going round on foot and meticulously comparing the details of the properties that you have sold data for. Great, now you have a really accurate pile of information about what has happened over the last period of time (however long you've been collecting it for). What does that tell you about what will happen to house prices tomorrow, or next week, or next month, or next year? Nothing at all.

It sounds to me like in an effort to compensate for your lack of experience of the housing market in general, you are trying to focus on pinning down various pieces of data in a way that really isn't helpful or even possible.

My advice would be: decide from your own life circumstances right now whether buying (vs renting or living with family) makes sense. If buying makes sense, work out your own budget to determine what you can afford (including if interest rates rise substantially). Look at the types of house you can afford in the area you want and decide whether that is acceptable to you. If not, look at smaller / cheaper houses, or less expensive areas.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127892/discussion-on-answer-by-vicky-reliable-sources-on-house-prices-in-the-uk-london).